# Docker deployment on windows local machine

Tags: angular, spring-boot, docker, containers

I'm trying to deploy a 3 tiered application. I've created a docker network of type bridge for the whole application. I'be deployed the DB, the **spring-boot** backend server and the **angular** front-end in separate containers. My backend server can access the DB, however when I'm accessing the frontend container and making a request to the backend container it gives an error that the backend is not found. The request to the backend looks like: http://backend-container:8080/login

Comment: You should try `http://localhost:8080/login`

Comment: Ask a detailed question with what you want, what have you tried and whats the problem. Dont be shy to show us some code. Check stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @veben is right, you should use http://localhost:8080/login. 
One quick way to check the ip assigned to those containers is using `docker exec -it <container-name> ip addr` and check for inet.